# RPC framework with API for event loop

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, rpc, event-loop

Is there RPC framework with good API for external event-loop ?

For example, i have my own custom nginx build, and for some reason I want use it as RPC client. Nginx under linux, by default, use epoll-based async IO. As I understand gRPC(google RPC) framework doesn't provide API for integration.
Is there any stable RPC frameworks for this problem? 
(also one of the requirements - C or C++ support)

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in google leads to [this page](https://grpc.io/docs/), with different options for different languages.

Comment: Have you read the question? Or just post this answer for reputation?

Comment: Well, yelling at answers is not going the best way to get help.

Comment: >> As I understand gRPC(google RPC) framework doesn't provide API for integration with third party event-loop.
>>  Is there any stable RPC frameworks for this problem? 

And you have shared link to gRPC without any relevant information.
It also is not the best way to give a help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to drive ZeroMq using an external event-loop. Even though I would not recommend ZeroMq if you need to interact with Java. Furthermore, it's not really an RPC framework. It offers request / reply and pub / sub. So you need to implement the RPC method dispatching on top of it and use something like protobuf / flatbuffers etc. yourself for serialization.

ZeroMq ist also still stuck with a license which may not be acceptable by all organisations as its non-standard.